# Changing from cardboard scene to another on UNITY

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sdk, google-cardboard

I'm with a problem while changing from Cardboard Scene to my other scene in `UNITY`, the problem is that the **divisor**, that middle vertical line don't disappear when I go to other scene, anyone knows how can I fix this issue ?

Comment: Actually what i did is ... run Google Cardboard Demo App for Unity , and than change the scene to other empty one ..

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that at some point called [DontDestroyOnLoad](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html).

So try to call [Destroy](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) on that object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but dont have DontDestroyOnLoad in the script and also have a comment saying exactly what you said "Developer may implement DontDestroyOnLoad to ......"

Answer (score 0):

Set Cardboard.SDK.VRModeEnabled = false when switching to a non-Cardboard scene.  (It is a bug on the SDK that needs to be fixed.)

Comment: I add Cardboard.SDK.VRModeEnabled = false; before call my Scene Application Level , but didnt work, middle line still shown , any other idea ?

Comment: <code>
//Back to my Default Scene
 public void GoToHome() {
  //Destroy(gameObject);
  //Destroy(transform.root.gameObject);
  Cardboard.SDK.VRModeEnabled = false;
  Application.LoadLevel("GoToHome");

 }
</code>